# Why do you need a controller account for nomination?

Tags: polkadot

Why do we need 2 account bond when we are nominating? What are the responsibilities/roles of both?

Comment: Note it is not "necessary", as in, you could set both the controller and stash as the same account. Long term, probably this is refactored, and the Proxy pallet will handle this abstraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to separate concerns. The stash can be a cold wallet that lives separately, the secrets locked away. Even if the controller, being a hot wallet in this example, gets compromised, an attacker could not steal the assets in the stash.